# Судьба — прохиндейка или прохиньдейка?

Tags: орфография, мягкий-знак

Я тут эту песенку Боярского **почитала-послушала**, и вот что удивительно: мне попался текст, где написано: ***судьбе-прохиньдейке*** назло.

Почему так? Мне кажется, что правильно: ***судьбе-прохиндейке***. Но как объяснить отсутствие мягкого знака. **По какому правилу** решается орфограмма?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Правило: **[ПАС под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=25)**

§ 30. Для обозначения мягкости **парного согласного перед согласными** буква ь пишется в следующих случаях.

б) перед буквами, **передающими мягкие согласные**, ь пишется только в тех случаях, когда в **других формах** того же слова или в **однокоренных** словах второй мягкий согласный **становится твердым, а первый согласный сохраняет мягкость, напр.: возьми (ср. возьму),** восьми (восьмой), ведьме (ведьма), во тьме (тьма), резьбе (резьба), косьбе (косьба), свадьбе (свадьба), молотьбе (молотьба), серьги (серьгам), коньки (конькам), дядьке (дядька).

**В остальных случаях** после буквы, передающей мягкий согласный, ь не пишется, напр.: разве, узник, грызть, кости, нести, **синдикат**, рецензия, ранний, пенсия, бантик, если, песня.

2. **ПРОХИНДЕЙ,** -я; м. Разг. Мошенник, жулик; ловкач. Знаю я этого прохиндея: меня не проведёт! Что твой п. опять задумал? <Прохиндейка, -и; мн. род. -деек, дат. -дейкам; ж.

Есть ли у **прохиндея** **[родственники](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9)?**  Да какие у него родственники, у этого прохиндея! **При склонении** прохиндей мягкость на твердость **не меняет.**

3. **Вывод.** Нет там мягкого знака!

**Диалог:**

— **А зачем** звук ***Н*** мягко произносить? И как **объяснить** это правило? И почему есть **исключения для Л и СК?** Как это всё соотносится с **фонематическим** принципом русской орфографии?

— **А зачем** вам это знать? Склоняйте и проверяйте.

— А почему **ошибка?**

— Слово редкое...  **Не запомнили** еще.

— Но ведь **правило** есть...

— Да кто его будет **применять**!

— Тогда у ж лучше **в словарь** посмотреть, чем склонять.

— И то дело...

— Тогда **зачем правило**?

— Ой, ну всё...

Comment: Меня очень раздражает, когда произносят фамилию Меншиков твёрдо, как будто если Ь пишется, то меняется произношение.

Comment: Да, вы правы.  И это влияние не очень понятного правила. Сочетание НШ/НЬШ пишется по слуху, там нет фонетического чередования, например: меньше, тоньше, но: траншея, планшет, шиншилла, великанша.  Эти сочетания произносятся в соответствии с написанием.

Comment: Так прав или неправ, я так и не понял?.. Если в соответствии с написанием, тогда без Ь в фамилии должна быть твёрдая Н, но она меня как раз и раздражает.

Comment: Нормально! А почему она должна быть твердой, сравните: меньше, уменьшить, Меньшиков. Меньшиков в Березове (историческая  картина Сурикова, известная персона в истории).  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Меншиков,_Александр_Данилович   Ш всегда твердый, поэтому НШ/НЬШ пишется по слуху.

Comment: Sharon, интересно, почему в этот список – "в остальных случаях после буквы, передающей мягкий согласный, *ь* не пишется" – попали слова "разве" и "если"? Они же вроде не произносятся с мягкими З и С: *разьве, есьли*.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Это нерусские (или немосковские) так говорят))   У меня твердое произношение, а оно по словарю только допускается.  РАЗВЕ
Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка
РАЗВЕ, частица \\ ра[з’]ве и допуст. младш. ра[з]ве.  ЕСЛИ \\ [jэ]сли и допуст. [э]сли; е[с’]ли и допуст. младш. е[с]ли.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Странный словарь :))

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ**

Мягкий согласный можно **выбрать иначе** (не только по правилу), но для этого надо познакомиться с пятью согласными звуками ***Т, Д, З, С, Н,*** которые называются **зубными**.   (Сюда же относятся ***Л*** и ***Ц***, но в этой орфограмме они не участвуют.)

Знакомство того стоит, так как зубные согласные являются **причиной многих орфограмм** (непроизносимые согласные, *ТСЯ/ТЬСЯ* в глаголах, взаимное влияние зубных и и шипящих звуков).

При произношении зубных согласных  кончик **языка** упирается в основании передних **зубов**, а различаются они по **способу образования** (смычные Д/Т),  фрикативные З/С, сонорный Н).

Эти согласные могут **взаимно смягчать** друг друга, а такое фонетическое чередование на письме **не отражается**. Второй звук должен быть **МЯГКИМ,** а первый **копирует его мягкость**
(тогда можно сказать,что у него **несобственная мягкость**). После первого звука ***Ь* не пишется.**

**Решение:**

**Прохиндейка**:  сочетание зубных согласных  ***НД***. Звук ***Д*** — мягкий, ***Н*** смягчается перед мягким ***Д***, но его несобственная мягкость не отражается на письме (нет ***Ь***).

Сравнить: ***мундир, командир***.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

Почему фамилия ***Меньшиков*** пишется с ***Ь***? В сочетании ***НШ*** нет фонетического чередования, выбор ***НШ/НЬШ*** делается по слуху. Дело в том, что ***Ш*** — всегда твердый, поэтому первый согласный имеет или не имеет собственную мягкость.

Аналогичная ситуация с ***январский*** и ***декабрьский***, то есть написание по слуху. Здесь ***С*** — твердый!

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150286/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.